# Sorting of an array alphabetically in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I am new to swift.I am trying one sample app in which I need to implement the sorting of an array in alphabetical order.I getting the json data and I am adding the titles in the array.Now i would like to sort that alphabetically.Here is my code .....

```
func updateSearchResults(data: NSData?)
{
    do
    {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

            if let blogs: NSArray = json["results"] as? [AnyObject] {
                print(blogs)
                for blog in blogs {
                    if let name = blog["original_title"] as? String {
                        names.addObject(name)
                    }
                }
                print(names)
                **let sortedArray = sorted(names, {
                (str1: String, str2: String) -> Bool in
                return str1.toInt() < str2.toInt()** // Here I am getting the Error Message
                })

            }
    }
    catch {
        print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The error message I am getting is **"Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableArray, (String, String) -> Bool)'"**

I tried a lot to achieve this but I didn't find the solution.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why are you choosing to use `NSArray` instead of a Swift `Array`?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

First convert `NSMutableArray` to the Array by using below line of code.

```
let swiftArray = mutableArray as AnyObject as! [String]
```

Use below line of code to sort the Array.

```
var sortedArray = names.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

Check below link for `sort` Closures.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Update for Swift 3.0

```
var sortedArray = swiftArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

Comment: It is showing the error like "Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'sorted'

Comment: @anushahrithi `sorted` was removed, use `sort` instead.

Comment: you must pass an array of sort descriptors (even if it's only one):

var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])

Answer (score 39):

Use this simple code of line to sort ur array

```
 let sortedNames = names.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

For **Swift 4** you can use only this

```
let sortedNames = names.sorted(by: <)
```

Comment: @Kenneth Yes, in this scenario this will also work fine

Comment: Since `names` looks to have the type `Array<String>` it wouldn't have the property `name`. Your call should look like `names.sort { $0 < $1 }`. That can even be shorted to `names.sort(<)`.

Comment: This doesn't take into account capitalization (and likely other things when translating to other languages). For example "Bag" would come before "art".

Comment: Also, you can now just write `.sorted()` to sort in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks @jjatie ... You can edit the answer and update if you have verified and tested the code

Answer (score 17):

Swift4

```
var names = [ "Alpha", "alpha", "bravo", "beta"]
var sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
print(sortedNames) //Logs ["Alpha", "alpha","beta", "bravo"]
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift 4(working code)

JSON response -> Stored in aryNameList

```
"DATA": [
{
        email = "iosworker@gmail.com";
        firstname = Harvey
},
{
        email = "poonam@openxcell.com";
        firstname = poonam
},
{
        email = "t@t.com";
        firstname = rahul
},
{
        email = "android.testapps@gmail.com";
        firstname = Chulbulx
},
{
        email = "t@t2.com";
        firstname = rahul
},
{
        email = "jaystevens32@gmail.com";
        firstname = Jay
},
{
        email = "royronald47@gmail.com";
        firstname = Roy
},
{
        email = "regmanjones@hotmail.com";
        firstname = Regan
},
{
        email = "jd@gmail.com";
        firstname = Jaydip
}
]
```

Code

```
    self.aryNameList = self.aryNameList.sorted(by: { (Obj1, Obj2) -> Bool in
       let Obj1_Name = Obj1.firstname ?? ""
       let Obj2_Name = Obj2.firstname ?? ""
       return (Obj1_Name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(Obj2_Name) == .orderedAscending)
    })
```

working every case (for ex: lowerCase, upperCase..)

Comment: Don't u think that using let Obj1_Name = Obj1.firstname! like this is a bad idea? I mean any force unwrap of nil String can crash ur program)

Answer (score 9):

For an array of objects:

```
items = items.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
        return item1.product.name.compare(item2.product.name) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    })
```

Comment: You might want to use lowercased() for the names just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var names = [ "Alpha", "alpha", "bravo"]
var sortedNames = names.sort { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
print(sortedNames) //Logs ["Alpha", "alpha", "bravo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 solution:

```
let yourStringArray = [ "beTA", "ALPha", "Beta", "Alpha"]
var sortedArray = yourStringArray.sorted()
// Result will be ["ALPha", "Alpha", "Beta", "beTA"]
```

Creds to jjatie